# Update Leaflet GeoJSON layer with data inside bounding box

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I'm using leaflet/JavaScript for the first time and I want to display a map, with a GeoJSON layer which change on every move… To only show points on the area.

This is my code source:

```
// Function to refresh points to display
function actualiseGeoJSON() {
    // Default icon for my points
    var defaultIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: '../images/icones/cabane.png',
        iconSize: [16, 16],
        iconAnchor: [8, 8],
        popupAnchor: [0, -8]
    });

    // We create each point with its style (from GeoJSON file)
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = '<a href="' + feature.properties.url + '">' + feature.properties.nom + "</a>";
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        var cabaneIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '../images/icones/' + feature.properties.type + '.png',
            iconSize: [16, 16],
            iconAnchor: [8, 8],
            popupAnchor: [0, -8]
        });
        layer.setIcon(cabaneIcon);
    }

    // We download the GeoJSON file (by using ajax plugin)
    var GeoJSONlayer = L.geoJson.ajax('../exportations/exportations.php?format=geojson&bbox=' + map.getBounds().toBBoxString() + '',{
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: defaultIcon});
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}

// We create the map
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://maps.refuges.info/hiking/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; Contributeurs d\'<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

// An empty base layer
var GeoJSONlayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);

// Used to only show your area
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
    actualiseGeoJSON();
}
function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
    actualiseGeoJSON();
}
function onMove() {
    // map.removeLayer(GeoJSONlayer);
    actualiseGeoJSON();
}

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 14});

// Datas are modified if
map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
map.on('moveend', onMove);
```

I have tried to remove the layer in my first function but GeoJSONlayer is not defined
I have tried to remove the layer in onMove() but nothing appears
I have tried to remove the layer in moveend event but I have an syntax error…

If somebody can help me…

*Sorry for my bad English, French guy ith french function names*

Comment: faut apprendre l'anglais mec ! :)

Comment: and you don't need the radius variable since you don't seem to draw a circle of the position accuracy ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I see you are using the leaflet ajax plugin.

The simplest way to get your map to work is to download all available data right at the start, providing a giant bounding box, and add it to the map just once. This will probably work just fine, unless there's insanely many cabins and stuff to download.

---

But if you wish to refresh the data regularly, based on the bounding box, you can use the refresh method in [the leaflet-ajax plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax):

> you can also add an array of urls instead of just one, bear in mind
>   that "addUrl" adds the new url(s) to the list of current ones, but if
>   you want to replace them use refresh e.g.:
>
> ```
> var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson.ajax("data.json");
> geojsonLayer.addUrl("data2.json");//we now have 2 layers
> geojsonLayer.refresh();//redownload those two layers
> geojsonLayer.refresh(["new1.json","new2.json"]);//add two new layer replacing the current ones
> ```

So initially:

```
var defaultIcon = ...
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) ...

// Do this in the same scope as the actualiseGeoJSON function, 
// so it can read the variable
var GeoJSONlayer = L.geoJson.ajax(
    '../exportations/exportations.php?format=geojson&bbox=' 
    + map.getBounds().toBBoxString() + '',{
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: defaultIcon});
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

And then for each update:

```
function actualiseGeoJSON() {
    // GeoJSONLayer refers to the variable declared
    // when the layer initially got added
    GeoJSONlayer.refresh(
        ['../exportations/exportations.php?format=geojson&bbox=' 
        + map.getBounds().toBBoxString() + '']);
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the layer as a property of the map, instead of as a `var`:

```
map.geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson.ajax(...)
```

And later refer to it as follows:

```
map.geoJsonLayer.refresh(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

this leaflet plugin is more suitable for your purpose, manage map events and zoom.
Caching remote requests and much more.

http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-layerjson/

```
var ajaxUrl = "search.php?lat1={minlat}&lat2={maxlat}&lon1={minlon}&lon2={maxlon}";
map.addLayer( new L.LayerJSON({url: ajaxUrl }) );
```

Extend L.GeoJSON with more features and support ajax or jsonp request. See the source code comments for more documentation.